# What is the best way to implement a long running event listener

Tags: android, service, listener

I am working on an Android application where I need to implement a listener that receives events and updates the application database and some UI elements when such events are received. The listener needs to run the whole time the application is running.

Can you guys give me some suggestion on how to implement this the best way ? **Some best practices ?**

PS : I was thinking about integrating this event listener in a service. What do you think ?

Comment: that depends on your events and if your activity is supposed to be visible the whole time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are thinking of using a Service for the same, inside the onStartCommand() of your Service, add START_STICKY as a return value. This will re-create your service if the Android OS kills it for lack of resources.
A best practice is using BroadcastReceivers and registering them in the Manifest.xml file. These run all the time and are not killed by the OS

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly how i implemented :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a class extending from BroadcastReceiver. Override the onReceive method where you update the application database.

Then you should use AlarmManager class to schedule the events. There are three ways of scheduling them: one time event using the set method, a repeating event using the setRepeating method and the setInexactRepeating.

Here is a good tutorial: [Refer this links](http://justcallmebrian.com/2010/04/27/using-alarmmanager-to-schedule-activities-on-android/)

Using this approach you will have the listener running even when your application is not running, and you would be able to receive events even when your mobile it's in stand by mode. This is something that you can't do with a service.

To wake up your mobile using AlarmManager don't forget adding to the Manifest file the next line (before `<application>`):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Hope this helps.